# I need to read the text displayed on the popup window in Web driver using Java

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

[image: Popupwindow]

I need to read the text displayed on the popup window in Web driver using Java. I am able to handle the popup window for closing. I don't know how to read the text displayed on Popup window and print it in Console.

I am not able to provide any HTML code for this because its a Modal Popup window.

Please help me on this. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: if this is your application, shouldn't you be able to capture the message **you're** gonna display on the pop-up?

Comment: Thanks for your early reply. It is the application i am working on but message displayed on Popup window is not able to read because it is a modal popup window not a normal popup where we can work without closing the popup window. without closing the Modal Popup window, we cannot work on the application anymore.

Comment: And that popup - is it javascript popup?

Comment: I found [this](http://selftechy.com/2011/07/05/selenium-webdriver-handling-javascript-popups) describing how to get the text of an alert box:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your screenshot, it looks like the "modal popup" you're trying to automate is generated by the JavaScript alert() function. If this is the case, the following code or something similar to it, should work.

```
// WARNING! Untested code written from memory without
// benefit of an IDE! May not be exactly correct!

// Switch the driver context to the alert
Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();

// Get the alert text
String alertText = alertDialog.getText();

// Click the OK button on the alert.
alertDialog.accept();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer JimEvans. I am able to read the Text present on the Popup window. But i have a issue here. My script is getting error out saying "Modal Dailog Present'. i am not able to handle it. Can you please suggest me on this issue also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the WebDriverWait object before? To expand on the previous answer, you may be able to do something similar to this, but I have not tested:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(5, TimeUnit.Seconds);

element.click();

// Wait for the dialog to show
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

// Switch the driver context to the alert
Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();

// Get the alert text
String alertText = alertDialog.getText();

// Click the OK button on the alert.
alertDialog.accept();
```

Also, you may have to switch back to the alert after getting the text. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now i am getting the error, i have used the alert.dismiss() method; so its not giving any error